# sapply returns a matrix instead of character vector

Tags: r, sapply

I have the following data:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(var =  c("A_new_1",  "B_new_2",  "A_old_1",  "B_old_2"), 
code = 001, desc = c('applied', 'not applied', 'applied','applied'))
> df_1
      var code        desc
1 A_new_1    1     applied
2 B_new_2    1 not applied
3 A_old_1    1     applied
4 B_old_2    1     applied
```

I would like to replace A_new_1 with 1_new_A, and so on. I want to use dplyr and replace all at once, this what I tried:

```
p <- list(c('1_new_A'), c('2_new_B'), c('1_old_A'), c('2_old_B'))

ptr <- list(c('A_new_1'), c('B_new_2'), c('A_old_1'), c('B_old_2'))

df_1 %>% mutate(var  = (sapply(1:4, function(i){ gsub(ptr[[i]], p[[i]], var)})))
```

this is what I get:

```
    var.1   var.2   var.3   var.4 code        desc
1 1_new_A A_new_1 A_new_1 A_new_1    1     applied
2 B_new_2 B_new_2 B_new_2 B_new_2    1 not applied
3 A_old_1 A_old_1 A_old_1 A_old_1    1     applied
4 B_old_2 B_old_2 B_old_2 2_old_B    1     applied
```

My questions:

1. why sapply returning a matrix?
2. how do I correct above solution and return a single character vector (`var`) in the input dataframe?

Comment: like this? `df_1 %>%
  mutate(var = imap_chr(var, ~gsub(ptr[[.y]], p[[.y]], .x)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better option using `dplyr` is probably the `recode()` function. For example

```
translate <- setNames(unlist(p), unlist(ptr))
df_1 %>% mutate(var  = recode(var, !!!translate ))
```

Basically you just need to create a named list for the translations and then inject that into the `recode()`.

`sapply()` is returning a matrix because you are looping over the values `1:4` so a value will be return for each numner 1 to 4, and you are using `gsub()` with `var` and in the `mutate()` the value of `var` is the entire column of values. So you are returning multiple values for each call to `gsub` so it gets transformed into a matrix.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for this efficient solution. Could you please explain    the three exclamation marks symbol (`!!!`) what is it?

Comment: See the [rlang guide on injection](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-inject.html)

Answer (score 3):

This might be simpler. First fix your example:

```
p <- c('1_new_A', '2_new_B', '1_old_A', '2_old_B')
ptr <- c('A_new_1', 'B_new_2', 'A_old_1', 'B_old_2') # Fixing typos
df_1$var <- p[match(df_1$var, ptr)]
df_1
#       var code        desc
# 1 1_new_A    1     applied
# 2 2_new_B    1 not applied
# 3 1_old_A    1     applied
# 4 2_old_B    1     applied
```

Or in dpyr:

```
df_1 %>% mutate(var=p[match(var, ptr)])
#       var code        desc
# 1 1_new_A    1     applied
# 2 2_new_B    1 not applied
# 3 1_old_A    1     applied
# 4 2_old_B    1     applied
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, but I really want to use dplyr only.